# How to animate multi part object diagrammatic explosion using NLA

Tags: animation, .fbx, gltf, nla-editor, unreal-engine

I wish to animate a mechanical part (train bogie) exploding and imploding for a realtime system (taqtile manifest) using an fbx export.
I have keyframed the actions shown below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then cycle back to frame 0 position at frame 500.
Frame 0-125 and frames 275-350 are hold positions.

I have successfully exported this as a straight keyframed animation, though the realtime system i am exporting to has the function to load animation sequences based on names which is what i need to achieve.
I am pretty certain this is achieved by "pushing" the keyframed actions to an NLA strip.
I have tried to simplify the sequence by just trying to do the same to four coloured boxes.
[image]
Even doing this i cannot work out how i can get the desired result.
Ideally i would export an object that would have the options of
a) Unexploded
b) Exploding
c) Exploded
d) Imploding

If I create an action which is then pushed to NLA how can I combine all of the NLA to occur simultaneously. ie all objects "explode" or "implode" or remain static.

I have access to a model that does what i need in the realtime and when i import it i see the following...
I note that the NLA tracks have the name of the animation that is selected in the realtime.
[image]

Any help much appreciated. I have only been using Blender for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

NLA isn't too much intuitive, but if you understood it, it's great.

So to take your 4 box example, you just need to animate once (if both ways are the same), so i have this animation here:

[image]

This looks now in NLA like this:

[image]

Now pushdown all actions:

[image]

Now go to edit -> duplicate

and move them like this:

[image]

Now you have to select the right actions again (don't know why, but in my case i didn't see the properties for the actions on the panel), so click the first, then shift select the others, then in then panel (press N if you don't see it) hold CTRL down and press "reversed"

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much Chris. I will try that out. That addresses how to reverse the animation in NLA. Any ideas on how to combine the four boxes animation so when exported they are all controlled by one animation name eg "all boxes explode" or "all boxes implode" rather than "box 1 explode"?